# Android: root-доступ программно

Tags: android, java

Собственно вопрос: кто-нибудь смог получить права root на девайс программно?
Я видел скрипт на sh, с которым еще возиться и возиться, и это все что нагуглилось. Видимо подобные вещи не афишируются и все же интерес огромный, ибо порой полезно, особенно для написания системных тулз.

Comment: Что значит 'программно'? Получение root-прав на Андроиде - это обычно танец с бубном, т.е. хак.

Comment: Спасибо, кэп. Я это прекрасно понимаю, но есть приложения(apk-и), которые дают эти самые права, соответственно есть способ программно их получить или выполнить пляски из ресурсов приложения или еще чего.
Кроме того, это вопрос интереса!

Comment: Так для каждого телефона алгоритм свой. Документированного способа с телефона получить root нет.

Comment: На то он и интерес, чтобы не было все так просто:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не смотрели пример DeviceAdmin из API Demos? Там для получения используется получение прав администратора через специальный диалог.
Я точно не знаю то ли это, что вам нужно, но думаю может пригодиться ...
В [доках](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) также пишут что есть возможность получить такие права, начиная с Android 2.2

Comment: Там использутся Administration API. Доку я эту тоже видел, но врят ли это то, что нужно. На сколько я понял, тут права даются не на всегда.

Comment: Узнали ответ на вопрос?

Comment: рут доступ программно не получишь. Надо ставить прошивку или запрашивать на тех прошивках на которых это разрешено

Answer (score 0):

Получение привилегий делается через вызов системной программы `su` (например с помощью функции `system` или `exec`). В рутованный телефон эта программа устанавливается с suid-битами. Если взять данную программу из cyanogenmod, она предварительно спрашивает у пользователя, хочет ли он наделить привилегиями вызвавшее её приложение.

Пример вызова из java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8750977/1566316